# Silverlight - Avoid project recompile action to apply layout change

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, recompile

When I code mobile applications for Windows Phone (Silverlight Platform) and I make some changes to the UI, I have to recompile the whole solution in order to apply them. This is annoying and takes several seconds as well because Visual Studio uninstalls the app which is on the connected device and installs it again. This happens for changes to the UI only, recompilation is not needed for code-part changes.

Can we avoid this problem?

Comment: I have this problem in my new projects as well. My old projects are still working fine. What Version do you use? I have VS2012 with update 3 on Windows 8.

Comment: Here is another question like this, having some suggestions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946879/xaml-is-not-updating-when-debugging-on-a-wp8-device

Comment: Same VS and Windows 8 here. The problem comes with both WP7.X and WP8 projects. As I could read, we can't solve it, have a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/fe0709e3-25e0-4387-ab38-55509861de25/why-we-need-to-rebuild-the-silverlight-project-after-changing-the-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I created a new project with VS2012 Update 3 and made settings to look like theese: [How do you get Visual Studio to recognise XAML changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202317/how-do-you-get-visual-studio-to-recognise-xaml-changes). Now everything seems to be working fine.